# Error in creating EntityManagerFactory - Error Exception in creating Entity

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

I am getting Error in compiling Entity ...I think  the error is in persistence.xml file but unable to find out the problem .can any one please tell the error

### persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="AP">
    <class>db.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/khan"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="eclipse.link.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend tables"/>
            <property name="eclipse.link.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createDDL_ddlgeneration.jdbc"/>
            <property name="eclipse.link.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
            <property name="eclipse.link.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
        </properties>
    
</persistence-unit>
```

### Eclipse Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.<clinit>(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:55)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:92)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
at Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatformDetector.checkPlatform(NoServerPlatformDetector.java:28)
at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformUtils.detectServerPlatform(ServerPlatformUtils.java:58)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.IsolatedHashMap.<clinit>(IsolatedHashMap.java:48)
... 6 more
```

Comment: It looks like [this is the source for NoServerPlatformDetector](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.1-RC1/org/eclipse/persistence/platform/server/NoServerPlatformDetector.java/#28), but I don't see how it could generate an NPE...

Comment: NPE is generated as in persistence.xml there is some bug due to which entity is not mapped with database table

Comment: It looks like you're missing an [eclipselink.target-server](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.1-RC1/org/eclipse/persistence/config/PersistenceUnitProperties.java#PersistenceUnitProperties.0TARGET_SERVER) property (checked [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.1-RC1/org/eclipse/persistence/platform/server/ServerPlatformUtils.java/#61)).

Comment: Please add `<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>`  after `<persistence-unit` in your `persistence.xml` file